# api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, windows-10

I am developing a C/C++ application using Visual Studio Community 2015.

I used to build my application the system library: OneCoreUAP.lib. I am using Windows 8.1.

I used the function if_nametoindex defined in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In the link they specifies that you require ONeCOreUAP.lib

but I found Another links that indicates another library: Iphlpapi.lib:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

When launching my app I getting the following error:

```
The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer. 
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

This is the message image:
[image: api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll is missing from your computer]

When searching the dll, I know from the this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt657574(v=vs.85).aspx

that:

```
Introduced into api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-1.dll in Windows 10.0.10240.0
```

I tried to update the Windows 10 SDK, But this did not solve the problem.

How to solve the problem? Should I upgrade my windows 8.1 to windows 10 to solve it?

Comment: What functions are you using that you think depend on that DLL?

Comment: If you use the Windows 10 SDK, then by default the program requires Windows 10 and will not run on older systems. In particular, the onecoreUAP library is not supported on Windows 8.

Comment: @andlabs: i added the named function in the question.

Comment: I am not sure how you got to that page, but it says the function is supported since at least Windows Vista. Its main page on MSDN is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408409(v=vs.85).aspx), and that page says you link against `Iphlpapi.lib` instead of `OneCoreUAP.lib`. `OneCoreUAP.lib` and that MSDN page are for Windows Universal Apps which are only supported on Windows 10 and newer (can an expert confirm this?), and you do not seem to be writing one. But I'm not fully sure what happened with you finding that page instead of the standard desktop one.

Comment: @andlabs: yes I get the page that indicates that you should link with OneCoreUAP.lib so I linked with it. I think I should link with Iphlpapi.lib.

Comment: @andlabs: yes thuis solved the problem. You can mark it as an answer and I tick it.

Comment: I'd make that an answer but I'm not fully aware of what the situation with that page you found is. That being said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The page you found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) appears to have to do with Windows drivers that link against the Universal App Platform runtime, which is only available in Windows 10 and up. `OneCoreUAP.lib` is the .lib file that represents the UAP runtime. If someone who knows more about this could enlighten me on the specifics of this, that would be helpful; I don't fully understand what's going on or how and hwy it works.

You are not writing one of these; instead, you are writing a desktop program. So instead, you want to look at the desktop program documentation. Usually this is the first thing that Googling for the function name in question will get you. In your case, [this is that page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408409(v=vs.85).aspx), and at the bottom of the page it says the function can be found in `Iphlpapi.lib`, so you must link aganst that `.lib` file instead.

The bottom of that page also says the function was introduced no later than Windows Vista, so you are able to use it on 8.1.